# Upload JUnit XMLs to Sonar from Hudson / Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, junit, jenkins, hudson

As a .Net developer, I am not fully familiar with the concept of pom.xml, however a bit of Googling gave me this:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.my_dept</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_dept_parent</artifactId>
    <version>14.03.00.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.my_dept.my_app</groupId>
  <artifactId>DB_UnitTests</artifactId>
  <version>15.01.00.50-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>DB_UnitTests</name>
  <properties>
    <sonar.junit.reportsPath>${basedir}\..\JUnit</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have been trying to upload JUnit test results from the "JUnit" folder within my Hudson workspace to our enterprise sonar instance. After Hudson is done with processing this POM, I see an empty page created on sonar with 0 issues and no mention of the unit tests. Looking at the build console, there is no mention of JUnit or anything that might indicate that the dependency failed to load.

I may be missing something obvious in the POM. Please let me know if you need any other info in order to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I normally used a combination of these three maven plugins: Surefire (unit tests), Failsafe (integration tests) and jacoco (report creation)

The properties in the pom.xml

```xml
    <properties>
        <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.outReportPath>target/jacoco</sonar.jacoco.outReportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.outItReportPath>target/jacoco-it</sonar.jacoco.outItReportPath>
    </properties>
```

And these three plugins

```xml
<build>
     <plugins>
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.15</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                        <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                        <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                        <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.15</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Ensures that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe Maven plugin are executed. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                                <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                                <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property is true -->
                                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.0.201403182114 </version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after unit tests have been run. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>${sonar.jacoco.outReportPath}</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after integration tests have been run. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>${sonar.jacoco.outItReportPath}</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
       </plugins>
</build>
```

See that the Integration tests must end with ...IntegrationTest and the other tests with ...Test.

In this example, there are used some profiles, that maybe could be useful. You can delete then and adapt the above code.

```xml
<properties>
    <!-- Only unit tests are run by default. -->
        <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
        <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
</properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>all-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>all-tests</build.profile.id>
                <!-- All tests are run. -->
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Used to locate the profile specific configuration file. -->
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <!-- Only integration tests are run. -->
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, however I don't use any of these test runners. I already have the junit xmls which U just want to upload to sonar.

Comment: Ok. If you do not get the answer, try this, maybe it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `packaging` element of the project is set to `pom`.  When this is done, maven will not run any goals except `install` (and perhaps `sonar` does not as well).  How about trying again after setting the packaging to `jar`?

Comment: This seems to have the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to make any changes in pom.xml.
Sonar interprets JUnit reports.
In Jenkins you need to have installed sonar plugin and add sonar as Build Step (select from combobox).
Next thing is you need to add post build action - Publish JUnit test result report and add expressions.

I use failsafe plugin for int tests, so expression is:

```
**/target/failsafe-reports/*.xml
```

For unit tests I use surefire plugin and expression is:

```
**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml
```

Separator for expressions is whitespace.

Hope that will help.